# Iphone / IOS App Store acceptance Phonegap - XML Feed

Tags: jquery, ios, html, cordova

We are currently building a HTML5 Phonegap app that we would like to release into the appstore as a free app when complete.

Our current plan is to use XML feeds to provide data to the app from a .NET backend - which will be parsed via ajax/jQuery in the HTML 5 app, though I've just been reading about Apple's acceptance criteria and discovered that they reject apps for using private API's?

Does this mean that my current xml/jquery plan would be rejected?  If so can anyone recommend a means of dynamic data transfer that would be accepted?

Also are there any other key factors of rejection to consider when building the app?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the private API is just a bunch of private functions BUILT IN iOS FRAMEWORKS, that are not listed in the documentation and that you can't use.

Creating a way to parse your feed is not the same as using one of these functions, you'll not be annoyed at submission for that.

Hope that helps.

Cyril